# Nested property inheritance in OpenAPI Generator/Swagger Codegen

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I'm trying to generate Java models using a Swagger schema provided to me by a third-party company, but generation either fails or does not produce the objects I expect. I'm not sure if it's the generator or the schema that's the problem.

Essentially, the schema has a parent object Pet with a property "attributes," where "attributes" has a property "size". The schema also has a child object Cat that "inherits" from Pet (references Pet in the 'allOf' statement) and itself has a property "attributes" with nested property "whiskerCount".

```yaml
Cat:
  allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/Pet'
      - type: object
        properties:
          attributes:
            type: "object"
            properties:
              weight:
                type: "string"
Pet:
  type: "object"
  properties:
    attributes:
      type: "object"
      properties:
        whiskerCount:
          type: "integer"
          format: "int64"
```

When using the Swagger editor (2.0), the UI model shows the result that the company that provided me the schema is trying to achieve:

```
Cat {
    attributes  {
        whiskerCount    integer($int64)
        weight          string
```

However, when attempting to generate models, the results are:

| Generator | Result |
| --- | --- |
| Swagger Codegen (2.2.1) | Generation fails: `getAttributes() in Cat cannot override getAttributes() in Pet` (return types incompatible) |
| OpenAPI Generator (4.3.1, 5.0.0, 5.1.0) | Generation succeeds, but generates classes 'Cat.java', 'CatAllOf.java', 'CatAllOfAttributes.java', 'Pet.java', 'PetAttributes.java'. Cat#attributes (type CatAllOfAttributes) contains only 'whiskerCount' and Pet#attributes (type PetAttributes) contains only 'size') |

Is there a way to achieve a 'combined' Attributes object (member variable of Cat) that contains both fields whiskerCount and size?

Comment: Looks like the problem is `attributes` since it's not part of the OpenApi specification, try to delete it. Take a look at the example here in the [OpenApi docs](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.0.md#models-with-composition)

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not part of the OpenApi specification"? In this case, `attributes` is just the name of a property in the Pet and Cat structures.

Comment: You may want to try openapi-generator v7.3.0 and enable the normalizer rule `REF_AS_PARENT_IN_ALLOF` (by setting to true), and see if that's what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Try bringing type and properties to the same level(allOf)

```
Cat:
  allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/Pet'
  type: object
  properties:
```

Comment: I was surprised when this _actually_ did the trick with the Java OpenAPI generator 4.3.1. The OP's variant does work with 4.3.0 (at least for me), but things keep changing rapidly even through minor or bugfix releases.